# Как узнать что данные из сервера изменились если я в другом компоненте?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-native, redux-thunk

Сделал маленький проект в котором использовал react,redux,redux thunk.Когда пользователь заходит в приложение все action делают асинхронные запросы и пополняют данные reducera.Но когда данные из сервера изменятся я должен перед загрузкой компонента отправить dispatch action а то данные не изменяется и это замедляет.Вызвать action в Shouldcomponentupdate тоже не вариант.Как уведемлят что данные изменились и reducer сам себя обновлял.

Comment: Тут надо на код постотреть

Comment: вообще то любое изменение данных в store должно приводить к dispatch action если вы используете redux.

Comment: Вы правы что любое изменение приводит в dispatch action и в моем приложение также ,но когда данные изменятся в сервере независимо от приложения то приложение не может обновляет reducer.Чтобы обновить reducer надо перед render компонента вывать dispatch action и в shouldcomponent и то замедляет приложение.А главный минус что если я в другом компоненте reducer но может обновить сам себя

Answer (score 0):

Пришел к такому подходу, позволяет избежать запросов для тех веток, которые сейчас "не нужны" пользователю, которые он не видит. Кроме этого после отправки экшна на загрузку у тебя есть возможность организовать очередь запросов к серверу и дальше разруливать по желанию. Так же важно выполнять side effects не в методах render или shouldcomponentupdate, а в componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate это гарантирует их выполнение, подробно описано в документации.

**Component**

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { needLoadContent } = this.props;
    if (needLoadContent) this.loadContent();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { needLoadContent } = this.props;

    if (needLoadContent && !prevProps.needLoadContent) {
      this.loadContent();
    }
  }

  loadContent = () => {
    const { contentActions } = this.props;
    contentActions.contentRequest();
  };

  const mapStateToProps = state => {

    return {
      needLoadContent: needLoadAllContentSelector(state),
    };
  };
```

**Redux**

```
  {
    data: null,
    fetching: false,
    needUpdate: true,
    errors: ?,
  },
```

**Selector**

```
(fetching, needUpdate) => needUpdate && !fetching
```